# Is the Roslyn CTP still available for Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, roslyn

My Google-fu has failed: I can only find downloads compatible with Visual Studio 2012.

I remember it being available for 2010 originally:

[Introducing the Microsoft “Roslyn” CTP - The Visual Studio Blog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx)

Is the Roslyn CTP still available for VS2010 SP1?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The latest version doesn't support Visual Studio 2010](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/09/17/microsoft-quot-roslyn-quot-september-2012-ctp-now-available.aspx), now that Visual Studio 2012 has launched:

> Following last Wednesday’s [official launch](http://msdn.com/vstudio) of Visual Studio 2012, we’re excited to announce that the Roslyn September 2012 CTP is now [available](http://msdn.com/roslyn) for [download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=228400) and provides support for VS 2012 RTM. Please note that Visual Studio 2010 is no longer supported by this CTP.

The older binaries are still available on [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/Roslyn) (scroll all the way down to Version History) which should still be compatible with VS2010, but as mentioned those are older builds. Gotta move along with the times, they say...

Comment: ... unless you're sat at a desk in a corporate environment, that is. Cheers, BoltClock.

Comment: @TimBarrass If you're sat a a desk in a corporate environment, I would be very careful about using software that didn't even hit beta yet.

Comment: @svick - except that if you want to use this for a REPL tool, then what is it really going to harm? I just moved jobs and they're not using 2012 yet and I *really* miss having Roslyn.